# Unity problem that wont let me start the game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, photon

> JSON parse error: Missing a name for object member.
> (Assets/Photon/PhotonUnityNetworking/Code/Editor/PhotonUnityNetworking.Editor.asmdef)

Ive been trying different things for so long but its not working.

Comment: Perhaps that file is corrupt. I'd remove the plugin and reimport it.

Comment: sounds like its expecting a dependancy and the asmdef cant find it

Comment: "Unity problem that wont let me start the game". Is it a built game? Is it from inside the Editor? Did you remove Photon? Was it a unitypackage installation and di you delete it? Give more details please.